# Universes indexed by Integers

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Can we assume universes to be indexed by integers. That is, assume a sequence of universes infinite on both sides,

$$ \dots \mathcal{U}_{-n-1} : \mathcal{U}_{-n}  \dots\mathcal{U}_{-1} : 
\mathcal{U}_0 : \mathcal{U}_1\dots \mathcal{U}_n : \mathcal{U}_{n+1} \dots$$

Then,

1. Does the assumption gives any kind of inconsistency.
2. In case we can do that can we say that any two universes are isomorphic because any construction we do in $n$-th universe can be done in both $(n+1)$-th and $(n-1)$-th universe.
3. What is a model for this type theory.

Comment: This is also something I have wondered about. I have tried constructing these in Agda using induction-recursion, but had trouble even constucting universes indexed by naturals.

Comment: What are your rules for moving between universes?  In the usual situation, certain constructions will move from $\mathcal{U}_n$ to $\mathcal{U}_{n + 1}$.  How do your rules work?

Comment: Without more details, it's difficult to say anything about this situation. For instance, how are you constructing types in an arbitrary universe? Usually, you can construct the base types in the lowest universe, and then constructions involving one universe live in the universe above it. Here, how do you form something in a lower universe?
In any case, the universes should not be isomorphic simply because they have the same type constructors, unless you have identical base types in each universe (and the model is syntactic).